# Raspberry cannot install anything via sudo apt-get install <x>

Tags: pi-2, update, packages

yesterday i bought a new Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.
Im trying to install java & other packages but when i try to install via command:

```
sudo apt-get install <x>
```

i get the error:

[image: Error]

i tried to with updating my packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

thats what i got:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: I take it you've rebooted and tried again? what's the output of `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock`? Also, this is a straight, standard, noting major changed install of raspberry pi OS?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screenshots.  They are not accessible to browsers for the visually impaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting should clear all file locks which are held by hung up processes. If somehow this doesn't help, run `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to see which process exactly is causing trouble.